# after embed my flutter app into android app keyboard overlapping text field but iOS keyboard working perfectly

Tags: android, flutter, layout, android-softkeyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I have a flutter app which was embedded into android and iOS also but the keyboard hides the textfield means not slide up textfield as per soft keyboard activated flutter layout not resize/adjust so entered information not show properly

[image]

[image]

Comment: wrap it in a single child scrollView, and set resize to avoid bottom insets to true.

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma thank you for your response

I am using listView.builder to create list and also use single scroll view but all time getting same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivityFlutter"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

<activity
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    />
```

we have to set property in Manifest.xml at Android app.